# Image will move when adding text

Tags: html, css, image, position

I am still a beginner and googled already for this question, but no answers. My 'welcome' image at the top will move a bit when I add some text somewhere else in my HTML.

It seems to happen when the text will come under my image, but I tried to set position to my welcome image to relative and absolute, same with my `<p>` text, but it will not help. I also tried placing my welcome image into a div, but no luck either.

(Please forgive me that I don't use relative paths yet).

This is my HTML from my Welcome image at the top of my HTML.

HTML Welcome Image

```
<img id="welcome"/>
<center>
<a href="file:///C:/Users/M%20de%20Witte/Desktop/html/index.html">
<img src="C:\Users\M de Witte\Desktop\html\welcome03vectorpng.png"    height="100px" /> </a>
</center>
```

CSS Welcome Image

```
#welcome{

height: 50px;
}
```

HTML P

```
 <p id="thisiswhatiliketdo">
 This is what I like to do
 </p>
```

CSS P

```
#thisiswhatiliketdo{

font-family: moon_flower_boldregular;
font-size: 30px;
float: right;
margin-top: 300px;
margin-right: 300px;

}
```

Comment: `<center>` has been deprecated and should no longer be used. Why they are still teaching this is beyond me.

Comment: Without knowing what this looks like now, and how it's supposed to look it's hard to help. That's why we generally require functional demos. You can use placeholder images if necessary.

Comment: What is the other option to center an image then? And when I removed center, other images were moving too.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/center

Comment: Thanks for the replies, but I don't get it. It's ok to leave the <center> behind, but it won't help too with the <div style="text-align:center">. I don't understand placeholder images too, I can post my full code in here if you would like too.

Comment: We don't understand what it is you are trying to do. You mention `<p>` tags but there are none on the HTML you provided. Make a demo, using a Stack Snippet or an online code demo site like JSFiddle.net or Codepen.io and we can **stop guessing**.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to guess what your design is supposed to look like by your description but it sounds like you are having trouble with image and text alignment. This example of HTML align attribute should be able to solve your problem so that you can place your welcome image above, below, or beside text without it moving as you add more to your page design.

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_img_align.asp

Click the 'Try Yourself' button to preview the code results.